# Concrete5 internationalization - how to duplicate pages with content inside

Tags: internationalization, concrete5

I have finished to build my website in english.
I duplicated the site in to Russian and I want to translate it.
The pages that were duplicated duplicated without the content.
How can I duplicate pages with content?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you're not already using the free "internationalization" addon, that might do what you want: http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/internationalization/

Comment: Good. The best solution is to use the internationalization addon. With it, you can copy pages with the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've installed the "Internationalization" add-on, you should go to the "Full Sitemap" link in the Dashboard Area. Create a new page directly under the root (this will be that page that becomes your new language's home page later on).

Once you have the new page, visit the "Multilingual" section of the dashboard. On the "Multilingual Content Setup" page, you'll select your language, ie. "Russian", for "Choose a Parent Page", choose the page you created under the site's top level. Then click "Add Content Section".

Once you have your new "Content Section", you can copy your default content section into your newly created Russian content section. In the "Copy Language Tree" section of the "Multilingual Content Setup" page, choose to copy from, for example, "Home - English" to "Home - Russian". Click "Copy Tree", this should copy the content into your new Russian "Content Section".

You can use this video to see the steps I described above: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hd936iaDLqw&feature=player_embedded